# How do I simplify an algebraic equation with respect to a specific variable?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following equation -- which is all in terms of `d`:

```
{{{{acc == {(d + d (-1 + 1/fpr) (-1 + 1/precision))/(
  d + d (-1 + 1/precision) + d (-1 + 1/fpr) (-1 + 1/precision) + 
   d (-1 + 1/tpr))}}}}}
```

and I want it to now express this in terms of d. I thought I could use

```
 Solve[acc, {d}, MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic ]
```

but I get an error message. Now I could do this by hand, but I'm new to *Mathematica*. I have read the documentation, but I am unsure what I have missed or got wrong.

Comment: You can't use curly brackets like they are parenthesis. They are used to build lists.

Answer (score 2):

First off: you have a lot of unnecessary bracket pairs. Your equation should be written

```
acc == 
  (d + d (-1 + 1/fpr) (-1 + 1/precision))/
    (d + d (-1 + 1/precision) + d (-1 + 1/fpr) (-1 + 1/precision) + 
      d (-1 + 1/tpr))
```

Second, since `d` can be eliminated from your equation, you can't get a solution in terms of `d`.

```
Eliminate[
 acc == 
   (d + d (-1 + 1/fpr) (-1 + 1/precision))/
     (d + d (-1 + 1/precision) + d (-1 + 1/fpr) (-1 + 1/precision) + 
       d (-1 + 1/tpr)),
   d] // Simplify
```

> ```
> fpr precision + tpr - precision tpr != 0 && 
> acc == ((1 - fpr - precision + 2 fpr precision) tpr)/
>          (fpr precision + tpr - precision tpr)
> ```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for help.  The unnecessary bracket pairs are what are generated by Mathematica and I have no idea why it does this... so that `Solve[tpr == d/(c + d), c` generates `{{c -> (d - d tpr)/tpr}}` - it's not me putting them in! How do I stop these being generated? When I use `Eliminate(acc,d)` I get an error saying "acc is not a well-formed equation" but if I manually delete all the {{{}}} then the elimination works as @m_goldberg  have suggested.

Comment: @NickRyman-Tubb [This explanation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/18476) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First, you use a wrong syntax for `Solve`. It should be something like

```
eq = acc == whatever the right hand side is;
Solve[eq, d]
```

Second, as m_goldberg has pointed out, your equation just can't be solved in terms of `d`! You must have done something wrong in your hand calculation.

Comment: Hello - yes I seem to have eliminated d! Still I cannot work out why my solve seems to generate lots of {{}}! I've only be a user for 15 mins!